# authenticate with identity server for more than one api

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

We have a website and a public api, both of which are defined as Clients in Identity Server:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return new List<Client>
    {
        // resource owner password grant client
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "API_RO",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },
            AllowedScopes = { "WEB_API" },
            IncludeJwtId = true,
            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
            AlwaysSendClientClaims = true                    
        },
        // OpenID Connect implicit flow client (MVC)
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "PUBLIC_SPA_APPLICATION",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                "WEB_API",
            },

            IncludeJwtId = true,
            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
        }
    }
}
```

And in the web service we are authenticating against the token that is sent

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceDiscovery serviceDiscovery)
{
    app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = $"{serviceInformation.Prefix}{serviceInformation.IpAddress}:{serviceInformation.Port}",
        RequireHttpsMetadata = false,                
        ApiName = "PUBLIC_SPA_APPLICATION", //"API_RO",<= PROBLEM HERE
        SaveToken = false
    });
}
```

The problem that I have is that the ApiName parameter only allows for one client to be set. I need to find a way for it to work for both clients that have come via the website and ones that have come via the API.

Currently I am getting the following error:

> Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience
>   validation failed. Audiences: 'PUBLIC_SPA_APPLICATION'. Did not match:
>   validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'API_RO' or
>   validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.

Comment: `ApiName` isn't where you 'set clients' - it's where you give a name to your API resource. In your `UseIdentityServerAuthentication` you should be setting `AllowedScopes`, which is where you can restrict which clients can access your resource (but not really, you are restricting scopes but clients are created with scope definitions) . Does that `Authority` definition you've set match the URL for the IdentityServer ?

Comment: Also just noticed you've said your public API is a client too ... is there a 3rd protected API/resource that this public API is consuming and so needs to get its own access tokens for? A more common pattern is you'd have the MVC app as a client, which requests access tokens to access the protected API, but maybe you're doing something different.

Comment: Hi Mashton, when I change the code so that AllowedScopes is now set to "WEB_API" I get a scope validation error. When I examine the JWT token for the web application (which is Implicit flow) the "WEB_API" scope doesn't seem to be there

Comment: Please share where you define your API resources for IdentityServer4.

Comment: Also show how you are requesting a token. You say it doesn't have the WEB_API scope in the response, so what scopes are you requesting when making the call?